# Excel offset with if formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, offset

I have been scratching my head trying to work this out, I would be grateful if you can help. 
The formula below offsets 3 places when it finds “Earnings for Period”.  However if that cell is enter or zero “0”, I want it to offset 4 places. Any suggestions?

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($C$2:$C$100,MATCH("Earnings for Period",$C$2:$C$100,0),1),0,3)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using Offset and Match instead of Vlookup?

Comment: Thats what i found to be easier. How will a Vlookup work in this situation?

Comment: i am open to changing the formula if it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things you could do. The easiest, though not very pretty:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP("Earnings for period",$C$2:$G$100,3,0)=0,VLOOKUP("Earnings for period",$C$2:$G$100,4,0),VLOOKUP("Earnings for period",$C$2:$G$100,3,0))
```

We enter 3 vlookup statements. The first is used in the comparison of the IF() statement and will return 0 if the result is either blank or 0 (Depending on the format of your data, if there is a zero length text "" you may need to check for that). Depending on the result, we either do a vlookup for the 3rd column or for the 4th column.